# I cannot install package spatstat.data. Is it possible to download the zip file and copy and paste in the R folder library?

Tags: r, download, package, qgis

[new error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gy84q.png)I have updated the package spatstat, which is divided into various packages. All of them are updated except one, spatstat.data. I have tried `install.packages("spatstat.data")` and `update.packages("spatstat.data")`

**Error Message**

[image: error message]

My question is: *is it possible to download the `spatstat.data` zip file from cran, unzip the folder, copy all the folders and paste them to the right library?*

I have seen this option in another post, which I wonder if will work, `install.packages("name of the package.zip", repos = NULL)`

I am using windows 10 and R 4.0.3 (updated to 4.2.2). I am using QGIS.

Comment: From the error message the issue seems to be that an older version of `spatstat.utils`(2.3.0)  is already loaded while `spatstat.data` requires `3.0.0`. Try with restarting your R session. Then try again.

Comment: @stefan I updated spatstat.utils yesterday, but apparently it hasn't been updated to the latest version 3.0.1, but rather to the version 2.3.0. Is there a way to tell R that I want to install the latest version of spatstat.utils? Many thanks

Comment: Maybe something went wrong. `install.packages("spatstat.utils")` should give you the latest version, i.e. `3.0.1`. Just checked on my Mac.

Comment: @stefan I have just updated spatstat.utils again but I still got the version 2.3.0. I am using R version 4.0.3 and in the package description it says that it was Built: R 4.0.5. Could be here the problem? Thanks again

Comment: Hm. The built version should not be an issue. Do you get any errors or messages when running `install.packages("spatstat.utils")`? And make sure to restart your R session. Especially on Windows. (;

Comment: @stefan I am running the script install.packages("spatstat.utils") in R console within QGIS, because in that way it updates my R library in QGIS, which is the one that my R scripts in QGIS use. Do you think that I could install spatstat.utils directly in R, and after copy the folder from R library and paste into QGIS R folder? Would it work?

Comment: Worth a try. What does `.libPaths()` return?

Comment: @stefan the error message that I get when installing spatstat.utils is this: there is a binary version but the source version is later. I attach a screenshot with the error message

Comment: On the cran page for [spatstat: Spatial Point Pattern Analysis, Model-Fitting, Simulation, Tests](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/spatstat/index.html), the required version of `spatstat.utils` is ≥ 3.0, but the binary version that you install is 2.3. So it looks like you will need to install the source version. This will mean compiling the source version, which requires `Rtools.` Your screen shot message says that `Rtools` is not installed, so you will need to install it.

Comment: In your first screen shot, in the first line after the red line, you can see a message about the same version issue. Personally, I would update to R 4.3 before I installed Rtools, as Rtools install is version specific [RTools: Toolchains for building R and R packages from source on Windows](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) (I see you are using windows and R ver 4).

Comment: @Isaiah thanks. It seems that I need to update my R version, which is 4.0.3 in order to install Rtools and be able to install the latest version of the package.

Comment: After you install `Rtools`, install `spatstat.utils` again, but this time, when you get asked "Do you want to install from sources the package which needs compilation? (Yes/no/cancel)" say Yes.

Comment: @Isaiah Thanks for your advice. I will do it like that

Comment: @Isaiah quick question from me. Have you used the package installr to update R? Is it a good option for a not very experienced user? thanks for your help

Comment: I do use it. Like it!

Comment: R 4.0 will work, if you are not comfortable with updating R.

Comment: @Isaiah many thanks. I will use the package installr to update my current version of R.

Comment: @david007, how did this go?

Comment: @Isaiah thanks for asking. I have just installed rtools42, OS: Windows 10, but I believe I need to do a further step in order to be operative rtools, because it doesn't seen to be working. I have tried to install "spatstat.utils", type "source" and is not working. Do you know what step am I missing in the installation of rtools? Thanks again for your help

Comment: Have you installed the devtools package?
`install.packages("devtools")` Once devtools is installed, load it using library, then try `find_rtools()`

Comment: Also, can you please run `R.version`?

Comment: @Isaiah I haven't installed devtools. I will install it this morning. By the way, what do you mind by "can I run R.Version?

Comment: @Isaiah I installed devtools. I have executed library() and I couldn't see Rtools, but there is a package called "tools Tools for Package Development" which I don't know if is actually Rtools.

Comment: I run  find_rtools() and I got
[1] TRUE

Comment: new R version, 4.2.2, OS windows 10

Comment: So my question is:If I want to install spatstat.data last version: install.packages("spatstat.data", type "source"), do I need to call first Rtools?

Comment: This is the error message I get when trying to install spatstat.utils: Warning in system(cmd) : 'make' not found
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'spatstat.utils'. I guess that "make" not found refers to Rtools, isn't it?

Comment: OK, I know what the problem is. I am running the scrip in R within QGIS and it doesn't find rtools. I run Sys.which("make") in R and it finds the path to rtools, but I run it in R within QGIS and it doesn´t find the path to rtools.

Comment: In the QGIS online manual, I found "R has to be installed on your computer and the PATH has to correctly set up. Moreover Processing just calls the external R packages, it is not able to install them. So be sure to install external packages directly in R. See the related chapter in the user manual." This makes me think you should be installing spatstat in R, outside of QGIS? Note, I have never used QGIS! Given you have Rtools successfully installed there, that would be good news! There is also a reference to making sure you PATH is set correctly

Comment: @Isaiah many thanks. You are actually right (I thought the same this morning). I am going to install spatstat directly in R library and I am going to set the path in QGIS directly to this library. I will do it along the week and will let you know the outcome. Thanks for your help once more time.

Comment: `PATH` probably refers to the windows environment variable. You set it in windows [Adding a directory to the PATH environment variable in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-a-directory-to-the-path-environment-variable-in-windows)